# How do I count the number of each item in an ArrayList, then display them?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have an ArrayList with multiple entries of shopping goods, including a name, id and manufacturer. I've had a look at hashmaps and Collection.frequency but I wasn't sure how to use them correctly.

for example, when I want to view the contents of the person's cart, it currently displays the content in the format:

```
item id:12345 | red t-shirt  | Brand 1 | $30.00
item id:54321 | blue t-shirt | Brand 2 | $35.00
item id:12345 | red t-shirt  | Brand 1 | $30.00
```

I want to list all of the items from that ArrayList but display those entries as:

```
item id:12345 | red t-shirt  | Brand 1  | $30.00  | x2
item id:54321 | blue t-shirt | Brand 2  | $35.00  | x1
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I can fetch the amount of each item in the ArrayList and display the amount of entries for each one?

Comment: yes you can do this in java...

Comment: Use a loop and a `HashMap<T, Integer>` to store the count of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the following classes:

- Product (containing ID, description, brand, price)
- CartItem (containing product, quantity)

Then your cart could simply implemented as a `List<CartItem>` or, if you want to quickly be able to change the quantity for a given product ID, as a `Map<Long, CartItem>` where the key is the product ID and the value is the CartItem for this product:

```
public void addProductInCart(Product product, int quantity) {
    CartItem item = map.get(product.getId());
    if (item == null) {
        item = new CartItem(product, quantity);
        map.put(product.getId(), item);
    }
    else {
        item.addQuantity(quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, i have actually liked your approach. But a little question: would not it be nicer if we use a function like `item.increamentItemCount()` and give an implementation of equal method based upon the id of `product` maintaining the contract with `hashCode()` function ? just curious to know

Comment: You can also do that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a HashMap
- Iterate over you list and

  - Add the entry if not present, with value 1
  - If Present increment the value
- At last iterate throw your HashMap (There is an EntrySet iterator) and print your ShoppingEntry (the Key) and the Amount (Value)

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem, you should follow following steps.

1. Create a class named Item and properly override equals and hashCode.

   ```
   public class Item {

   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String brand;
   private Double price;

   public Item(Integer id, String name, String brand, Double price) {
       //...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj == null) {
           return false;
       }
       if (!(obj instanceof Item)) {
           return false;
       }

       Item other = (Item) obj;
       return this.id.equals(other.id)
               && this.name.equals(other.name)
               && this.brand.equals(other.brand)
               && this.price == other.price;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return 31 * this.id.hashCode()
               + this.name.hashCode()
               + this.brand.hashCode() 
               + this.price.hashCode();
   }    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return String.format("item id:%d | %s  | %s  | $%f",
                             id, name, brand, price);
    }
   }
   ```
2. Create a HashMap to count the items from list.

   ```
   Map<Item, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new Item(12345, "red t-shirt", "Brand 1", 30.00));
   list.add(new Item(54321, "blue t-shirt", "Brand 2", 50.00));
   list.add(new Item(12345, "red t-shirt", "Brand 1", 30.00));

   for (Item item : list) {
       Integer count = map.get(item);
       map.put(item, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);

   }
   ```